# Adding less file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, jquery-chosen

ive been wondering how to add .less files to my page because im quite new to css. So i have no idea what are ppl talking about.

Ive been learning a new chosen jquery for bootstrap. Here is the link

```
https://github.com/alxlit/bootstrap-chosen
```

And the problem is, i dont know how to install these features on my page. When i read the readme.md files, it said that i just need to do this :

```
// Add this to the bottom
@import "../../bootstrap-chosen.less";

bootstrap-chosen $ lessc bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css
bootstrap-chosen $ firefox example.html
```

But i dont have any slightless idea where to put this code.
Can you guys tell me where should i put this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Less` files you need to compile them to `css`.  There are various ways to do this depending on your chosen build tool.

The [Less website](http://lesscss.org) shows you how to install and compile `Less` files with node.js

From less.org

Install Less with Node.js

```
$ npm install -g less
```

Compiling Less from the command line

```
$ lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

This will then give you a css file you can link to from your html page.